# Maximize probability of working with the smartest person in a group of people.

Tags: probability, optimization

My biggest regret in choosing courses in university was choosing statistics over probability. Hence, I have a problem approaching this question, and fear my skills in probability are insufficient. However, I would like to see a method of approaching this problem:

Imagine that you're in a class of $2N$ (for $N$ a natural number) students, and the teacher wants you to form pairs. The teacher has a box with $2N$ chopsticks, where the numbers $1,...,N$ are written on the bottom of each chopstick. Each student in the order of a completely random class list, draws one chopstick (at random) from the box, and is paired with the other student drawing the same number. Selfish as you are, you would like to be paired with the smartest student (possibly other than yourself). Now assume that we can assign a measure of skill to each person, also ranging from $1,...,2N$, with $2N$ being the best, where each student has a unique skill level.

Assuming you know everyone's skill level, where on this class list do you want your name to be? More specifically, how does this position change with respect to your skill level?

As you might have guessed, this problem came to me in real life - and so I have no solution key to look at for help. It also reminds me to a certain extent of the Monty Hall problem, but I don't know how to apply any of that knowledge here - or even if it reasonable to do so.

I tried writing an R script (very statistics-y I know), but as I couldn't quite figure out how to formulate the problem it didn't get me very far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the drawing is done "at random." all pairings are equally likely. Your skill level, and when you draw, are irrelevant. The probability you will be paired with the person in the rest of the group who is smartest is $\dfrac{1}{2N-1}$.